# Display similar products with same attributes

Tags: javascript, forms

I am using wordpress to build a website to sale products. The product data feed comes from the vendor's server. When someone clicks on a product, I want to display a few similar products at the bottom of the page.

Since each product has a price, size, color, etc attributes, my approach is to capture these attributes in a hidden form, and do a search on vendor's product list and return the results.

Is this how you would do it? If so, how do I limit the results and only return 4 products?

Comment: Some description of the technology being used to communicate with the database would be helpful. Most databases have syntax in their query languages that let you limit the result set (e.g. TOP(n)). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx

Comment: Can this task be achieved with jQuery or PHP?

Comment: Probably. But you haven't provided any details on the various components involved. The entire question suggests you're a bit out of your depth so I'd suggest breaking it down and just trying to figure out how to get any query results from the vendors server to the visitors browser, before worrying about the details of what the right kind of query is.

Comment: I agree. I think I am going to try to use a hidden form to submit the query.